# Order Array by NextPageID field

Tags: php, sql, mysql, linked-list

I have info in a database that needs ordered in a weird way. I have a really simplified version below.

I need them to be output using PHP in the order that is being dictated by the NEXTPAGEID column. Someone told me to just loop through the values but I just can't figure out the proper way to loop through them like this.

```
ID: 1; NEXTPAGEID: 3  
ID: 3; NEXTPAGEID: 118  
ID: 9; NEXTPAGEID: 10  
ID: 10; NEXTPAGEID: 515  
ID: 11; NEXTPAGEID: 12  
ID: 118; NEXTPAGEID: 9
```

So the order I really need is

```
ID: 1, 3, 118, 9, 10, 515, (whatever the NEXTPAGEID of 515 is)
```

, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This requires a support for recursive queries which `MySQL` lacks.

You could emulate it like this:

```
SELECT @r := 1, @c := 0 -- the first id

SELECT  t.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  @r AS _current_id,
                @r :=
                (
                SELECT  nextpageid
                FROM    mytable
                WHERE   id = _current_id
                ) AS _next_id,
                @c := @c + 1 AS _orderer
        FROM    mytable t
        ) q
JOIN    mytable t
ON      t.id = q._current_id
ORDER BY
        _orderer
```

Comment: This seems to be working. I couldn't quite get the other PHP methods implemented properly.

Comment: This is sort of working, but it's not actually sorting the results that come back. It's just adding an extra column (_current_id) that has the correct sort, but it doesn't re-sort the original ID column.

Comment: This one is giving me sql errors. Should there be a comma after AS _orderer? Also, I don't see 1.id declared anywhere until the ON statement and that seems to be where an error is coming from.

Comment: The query works but the ORDER BY doesn't affect it at all. Thanks for all the help btw.

Comment: @jaxbulls: did you initialize `@c` before the query? Add the `_orderer` field to the output and see what does it return.

Comment: Yes. When I add it to the output, it just outputs I think is the row # of that row in the table.

Comment: @jaxbulls: just noticed a bug in the query. Try now.

Comment: @Quassnoi That's it! Works perfectly, thanks so much for the repeated assistance.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` ORDER BY `NEXTPAGEID` ASC
```

Comment: Not what he's looking for. Read the question, look at the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do recursive SQL queries, you can sort in PHP:

```
function sort_by_nextpageid($array) {

    $index = array();
    foreach($array as $row) $index[$row['ID']] = $row;

    $result = array();
    $id = 1;
    while (isset($index[$id])) {
        $result[] = $index[$id];
        $id = $index[$id]['NEXTPAGEID'];
    }

    return $result;
}
```

And call the function like this:

```
// rows from the db

$array = array(
    array('ID' => 1, 'NEXTPAGEID' => 3),
    array('ID' => 3, 'NEXTPAGEID' => 118),
    array('ID' => 9, 'NEXTPAGEID' => 10),
    array('ID' => 10, 'NEXTPAGEID' => 515),
    array('ID' => 11, 'NEXTPAGEID' => 12),
    array('ID' => 118, 'NEXTPAGEID' => 9),
);

$array = sort_by_nextpageid($array);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `table_name`";
$result = mysql_result($query);

if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
    while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $testArray[] = $rows[ID];
    $testArray[] = $rows[NEXTPAGEID];
}

$result2 = array_unique($result);
$lastArray=array_values($result2);
```

Comment: http://tr.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php it checks values of an array and deletes if there are same values and deletes them.